# Implement incremental load from AWS RDS SQL Server to Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds

I need to transfer data from DWH(AWS RDS MS SQL Server) to Amazon S3. Data in DWH can be updated, not only added. Did someone do such a pipeline? Data in DWH is updated every 10-15 minutes.

Comment: Is there a last_changed timestamp or something along those lines that lets you detect which rows actually changed or does that logic need to be implemented by you as well?

Comment: I can add this column

Answer (score 0):

[AWS Database Migration Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/Welcome.html) can help you with that, it also supports [ongoing replication](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Task.CDC.html) and SQL Serve is fully suported

there's a full walktrought solution here: https://dms-immersionday.workshop.aws/en/sqlserver-s3.html

they are using SQL Server on EC2, but you can change the source to RDS

[image]